# Error while using gulp in semantic-ui

Tags: path, gulp, semantic-ui

I have the error

> cannot find UI defintion at path

```
C:\user\myuserid\semantic\src\themes\amazon\elements\button.less.
```

I have changed the theme to amazon at **theme.config** file but when run **Gulp** i receive this error. Can anyone please help

Comment: to fix this issue change line 61 in the file tasks.js from  /.\/themes\/.?(?=\/)/mg to  .*(\/|\\)themes(\/|\\).*?(?=(\/|\\)) and rebuild it will works

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, change line 61 in the file *tasks.js* from `/.\/themes\/.?(?=\/)/mg` to `.*(\/|\)themes(\/|\).*?(?=(\/|\))` and rebuild.